# How to change the value of z-index

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, z-index

I'm using C#, ASP.NET and HTML/CSS and I need to change the z-index.
There is a if else which says how many graphics should be rendered on one site.
The maximum is four graphics.
So I've got four different div's. Their z-index should change automatically if there are more graphics on one site.
What is the easiest way to do that?
I think it would be easy to write it inside the if else with a javascript but I dont know how.
And If there is a javascript how do I put it in the if-else in c#?

These are the div's:

```
</asp:Content><asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <div class="contentwidth" id="chartdiv">
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>


        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:0; ">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        <div  ID="chart2"style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
            <script src="../Scripts/secondChart.js"></script>
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div> 
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And is this javascript even right?

```
function secondChart(chart2) {
    $(chart2).css('z-index', 0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `$("#chart2").css('z-index', 0);`

Comment: It still doesn't affect the z-index of the chart2.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware (as jquery tag is missing) that the javascript fuction is in fact jquery function, and jquery script reference is needed for this function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Style** keyword to access the css:

```
function secondChart(chart2) {

    chart2.Style["z-index"]="0";
}
```